# I need some clarification on Java while loop

Tags: while-loop, boolean-logic

Why does this code work to exit the while loop

```
while (!(!(x < 5) || !(y < 5)))
```

but this does not

```
while ((x < 5) || (y < 5))
```

Comment: `!(!(x < 5) || !(y < 5)) == (x < 5) && (y < 5)`

Comment: De Morgan's Laws https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both expressions are not equivalent,

```
!(!A||!B) = A && B
```

Check de Morgan's Law

http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/demorgans-theorems/

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down:

```
(!(!(x < 5) || !(y < 5)))
```

`!(x < 5)` is equivalent to `x >= 5`, and similarly for `y`, so the above is equivalent to

```
!(x >= 5 || y >= 5)
```

The expression in parentheses is `true` if either `x` or `y` is 5 or greater.  For the expression to be `false`, therefore, *both* `x` and `y` must be less than 5--since if either one were greater than or equal to 5, the parenthesized expression would be `true`.  The `!` means the whole expression is `true` if the parenthesized part is `false`.  Therefore, the expression is `true` only if both `x` and `y` are less than 5.  That is, it's equivalent to

```
x < 5 && y < 5
```

This is an application of DeMorgan's law, but you don't need to memorize or understand the law to see how it works.  All you really need to do is think through the expression and figure out under what conditions the expression will be true or false.  (If you have a more complex expression with lots of variables, DeMorgan's law could be useful.  But in that case, it's best to just break the expression down and introduce some intermediate `boolean` variables anyway; otherwise you won't be able to understand what you've written and neither will anyone else.)